ssh premission denied()
I am trying to ssh to an ubuntu server 22.04 on a raspberry pi 3 on a local enviroment. at first I simply used the ssh ubuntu@192.168.XX.XX command and I got the premission denied (publickey) error! so I modified the sshd_config file and uncommented the PasswordAuthentication yes and PublickeyAuthentication no lines. after another try, I got the premission denied() error (which I was told is shown when you enter wrong password but I am entering the correct password). the interesting part is that I am able to ssh from ubuntu server to myPC but not the other way around. I was finally able to ssh using puclickey but it's be much easier for me and my colleague to connect to raspberry pi using password authentication specially since it's in a local network enviroment.
does anyone have any idea of how to ssh using password?
edit: here's the important parts of the output for ssh -vvv command
amir@amirux:~$ ssh -vvvv ubuntu@192.168.179.15
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.179.15 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/amir/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/amir/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.179.15 [192.168.179.15] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
.
.
.
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@192.168.179.15's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
Permission denied, please try again.

it seems that I have entered the wrong password, but I'm 100% sure it's correct. as someone mentioned in the comment section, cloud init seems to be installed on RPi, could that prevent password authentication?

Did you restart ssh service after making the changes?

yes I ran the systemctl restart ssh*. I am wondering maybe there is a line in sshd_config of server not allowing me to ssh to server using password but I couldn't find any other related line other than passwordAuthentication.

And myPC is set up properly and by the way what are the specs on myPC?

OS of "myPC" ? I assume it is not Windows and hopefully a newer type of Linux.

OS of my PC is ubuntu 22.04 desktop . didn't mention it because I had the same problem when I tried with other OSs

The raspberry pi version of the Ubuntu server may use cloud-init to configure ssh to use key based authentication.

You can use the -vvvv switch in the ssh command to have a very verbose output to see where it is failing: ssh -vvvv ubuntu@192.168.xx.xx. copy the output of this command and paste it directly into your question and format it as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

thanks, I edited the post <3

thanks to @user68186 I was able to solve the issue.

cloud init on RPi can interfere with password authentication. I found this out by checking cloud init logs using less /var/log/cloud-init.log and seeing it was modifying ssh configurations and overwrting its files. the /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf file path caught my eye in the log file. so I opend the file and saw that there's a passwordAuthentication no line there! simply changed it to yes and now the ssh login using password works just fine.
thanks everyone for your help and hope anyone with the same problem finds this solution helpful <3

